# Get specific values from JSON array

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

So I have used asynctask to access a json file hosted online. I was able to display the json in my Android application. Now I want to display certain values from the json file. Below is the json file I've used.

```
https://feeds.citibikenyc.com/stations/stations.json
```

For example let's say I want to show only the id's from this json. How can I do this?

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (pd.isShowing()){
        pd.dismiss();
    }
    txtJson.setText(result);    
}
```

Here I have got the complete json value in 'result'

PS: complete asynctask

```
   private class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = new ProgressDialog(GetJson.this);
            pd.setMessage("Please wait");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null; //BufferedReader reads text from the input stream


            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]); // params[0] is the first value in String..params (String..params can
                                                //have any no.of string parameters )
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect(); //not necessary.works without this.

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();  // A string buffer is like a String, but can be modified
                String line = "";

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line+"\n");
                    //Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);   //here u ll get whole response...... :-)

                }
                //Log.d("BufferTest",buffer.toString());
                return buffer.toString();



            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  //Here the 'result' is whatever that is returned from the
                                                        //doinbackground method (Ex: buffer.toString(); )


            try {
                JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("stationBeanList");
                String id = "";
                for(int i =0; i<jsonarray.length();i++){

                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    id = jsonObject2.getString("stationName");
                    txtJson.setText(id);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



         super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pd.isShowing()){
                pd.dismiss();
            }
            //txtJson.setText(result);


        }
    }
```

Comment: iterate through `stationBeanList` array and get `id` from each `jsonObject`.

Comment: You should take a look on [`JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Comment: see my answer bellow

Answer (score 1):

If you Need Example Then Follow [this link](http://androidcss.com/android/fetch-json-data-android/).

First create Model

```
public class StationBean{
    String id;
    String stationName;

    StationBean() {
    } 

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    } 


}
```

Now if you want to display data then you need to use `Recycleview Adapter`

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {
    List<StationBean> StationBean;

    RVAdapter(List<StationBean> StationBean) {
        this.stationBean= StationBean;
    }

    @Override
    public StationBeanViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
        StationBeanViewHolder pvh = new StationBeanViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.stationName.setText(stationName.get(position).stationName);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (stationName!= null) {
            return persons.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public static class StationNameViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView stationName;


        PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            stationName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.stationName);

        }
    }
}
```

Then Your Activity side write following:

```
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

    final RVAdapter rvAdapter = new RVAdapter(personList);
    rv.setAdapter(rvAdapter);


  try {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray stationBeanListJSONArray = null;
    stationBeanListJSONArray = obj .getJSONArray("stationBeanList");

    for (int i = 0; i < stationBeanListJSONArray .length(); i++) {
        StationBeanperson = new StationBean();
        JSONObject jObj =stationBeanListJSONArray .getJSONObject(i);
         person.Id = jObj.getString("id");
         person.stationName=jObj.getString("stationName");
         personList.add(i, person);
    }
    rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the result with following code :

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("stationBeanList");
            String value = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                value = jsonObj.getString("stationName");
                Log.d("TAG", "stationName :" + value);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //  txtJson.setText(result);    
    }
```

Comment: this works but i only see the value from last object.

Comment: can you post your complete asyntask with log ?

Comment: i've added the complete asynctask in question.please check. Also i debugged it and checked.. it also shows only one value.

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);  here jsonObject2 shows only one record.That is the last record.

Comment: @user3852473 You had mistake in code, you are continuously changing the same textview data so it happens . " txtJson.setText(id); " write bellow it "Log.d("TAG", "stationName :" + id); " and check it will print all .

Comment: so i have to use a listview?

Comment: @user3852473  yes you have to use listview and create the arraylist of values in side postexcute & pass that arraylist to you listview Adapter.